# Deliver json file via Angular routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular8

I need to deliver a static json file in my angular application for an external provider to use.

> for example: http://angular-app-url:4200/app-test.json

When I do routing, it is always for a component or its just redirect to another path. how can I achieve this to deliver this  json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `angular.json` file under `options` look for the `assets` entry and add the following:

```
"assets": [
    "src/path_to_your_file/app-test.json",
]
```